# ¿Es normal que las dependencias recien instaladas en PHP no aparezcan en el listado?

Tags: php, json, ubuntu

Estoy instalando php y sus dependencias en Ubuntu, estoy siguiendo este tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_FlO_T9BmA

use el comando

```
apt-get install php-json
```

Y como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen, la instalación fue un éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al usar el comando

```
php -m
```

El listado que dió fue el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, no aparece el módulo de JSON. Lo más curioso es que use el mismo método para instalar ctype, y éste sí  aparece en el listado.

¿Esto es normal o hay algo malo con la instalación?

Investigando leí sobre un archivo llamado php.ini , ¿donde se encuentra ese archivo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para encontrar el fichero *php.ini*, crea un fichero de texto en tu servidor que se llame `phpinfo.php` que tendrá la línea:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Accedes desde la web con localhost/phpinfo.php (o la ruta donde lo hayas creado) y buscas *Loaded Configuration File*. Ahí te aparecerá la ruta del archivo **php.ini**.

Comprueba también si aparece el módulo de PHP y el de JSON, si no aparece, suponiendo que no reiniciaste el servicio, debes hacerlo para que los cambios surtan efecto. Usa el comando

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

o en su defecto

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Como puede usar PHP desde la línea de comandos, se podría hacer en menos pasos ejecutando directamente `php -r 'phpinfo();'`. De ese modo no hace falta iniciar el servidor, crear el fichero y visitarlo desde un navegador. Y si quiere ver directamente la ruta de php.ini, se podría hacer `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep 'php.ini'`

Comment: Yo compartí la forma que yo sabía, no por no ser la manera más rápida, es inválida. Le invito a responder a la pregunta en vez de responder a mi respuesta para que le sea útil al OP su respuesta :).

Comment: Mi comentario no tiene entidad en sí para ser una respuesta propia y no dice que la publicación en la que está sea incorrecta o inválida. Simplemente expone una manera alternativa para hacer una parte de lo que se pone en esta respuesta.